# Jquery how to place a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trashcan which appears on the right side of the text ("cell.value.name") when I mouseover. But I need it to be appear on the right side of the text. Any ideas how to do it?

```
if (cell.direction == 'out') {
          var btnColumn = $('<div><div class="cellName" data-cellId="' + cell.fatherId +'" data-direction="' + cell.direction + '" +">' + cell.value.name + '</div></div>')
        } else {
          var btnColumn = $('<div><div class="cellName" data-cellId="' + cell.fatherId +'" data-direction="' + cell.direction + '" +">' + cell.value.name + '</div></div>')
        }
```

Event listener ;

```
$(document).off('mouseleave', '.cellName').on('mouseenter', '.cellName', function (event) {
var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
 var trashCan = $('<button type="button" title="Remove" class="btn btn-default btn-xs x-button-icon btn-delete-port" data-cellId="" data-direction=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>');
$(elem).mouseenter(function() {
   // $(this).append(btnColumn);
   trashCan.appendTo($(this));
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
   trashCan.fadeOut();
  });


});
```

Comment: A functional example and your html-markup would be nice

Comment: If you made a js fiddle then you can get answers very fast..

Comment: where you have declared cell variable.